# mdadm does not let me set --size manually, but grows to the same size later

Tags: mdadm

I'm trying to make raid1 out of 2 disks the size of which differs a lot (ec2 provides iops based on disk size, so I want to have more iops, but don't care about losing some free space).

However when I set the size manually, I get `is smaller than given size` error, **but** I can set the size lower, then grow *to the size I originally wanted*:

```
[~]# size=$( cat /proc/partitions | grep xvd[mb] | awk '{print $3}' | sort -n | head -n1 )
[~]# size=$(( size - 8192 ))
[~]# echo $size
15988224
[~]# yes | mdadm --create /dev/md0 --metadata=1.2 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 --size=$size --bitmap=internal --write-behind=1024 --assume-clean /dev/xvdb --write-mostly /dev/xvdm
mdadm: /dev/xvdb is smaller than given size. 15988152K < 15988224K + metadata
mdadm: /dev/xvdm appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Wed May  6 07:35:37 2015
mdadm: create aborted
[~]# size=$(( size - 18192 ))
[~]# yes | mdadm --create /dev/md0 --metadata=1.2 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 --size=$size --bitmap=internal --write-behind=1024 --assume-clean /dev/xvdb --write-mostly /dev/xvdm
mdadm: /dev/xvdb appears to contain an ext2fs file system
    size=15996416K  mtime=Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
mdadm: /dev/xvdb appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Wed May  6 07:35:37 2015
mdadm: /dev/xvdm appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Wed May  6 07:35:37 2015
mdadm: largest drive (/dev/xvdm) exceeds size (15970032K) by more than 1%
Continue creating array? mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
[~]# mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max
mdadm: component size of /dev/md0 has been set to 15988224K
```

So why does not it allow me to set the size to 15988224 from the beginning, only after growing?

Comment: Why do you want to explicitly specify a size in the first place? mdadm would by default use all available space

Comment: @Dan, sometimes I use the mdadm with `missing` device, e.g. I create raid from a 20gb disk with data + missing device, add a 16gb disk and have the data resync to the disk. Without `--size` it would not let me add the second disk

Comment: Ugh, you want to use disks that are not the same size. Ok. Check mdadm manual page, there are two important notes, size units (may depend on mdadm version) and reserved space for superblock:  --size=  Amount (in Kibibytes) of space to use from each drive in RAID levels 1/4/5/6. This must be a multiple of the chunk size, and must leave about 128Kb of space at the end of the drive for the RAID superblock.